# Converting Varbinary(Max) String to Image Format in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to convert `varbinary(max)` data in string format to image. I am trying below code but getting error

> "parameter is not valid"

at line

```
System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Here is the complete code.

```
string stringFromSQL = "0x6100730064006600";
List<byte> byteList = new List<byte>();

string hexPart = stringFromSQL.Substring(2);

for (int i = 0; i < hexPart.Length / 2; i++)
{
    string hexNumber = hexPart.Substring(i * 2, 2);
    byteList.Add((byte)Convert.ToInt32(hexNumber, 16));
}

byte[] imgData = byteList.ToArray();

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgData))
{
    System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
    image.Save(@"D:\Images\Photo.jpg");
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Muhammad Kamal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because your **stringFromSQL is incorrect**. You can test with the following code

Step 1: load image to memory in my local computer

Step 2: get the bytes from image

```
[Note]: you can try the get the string from the binary
```

Step 3: generate another image using your given code

```
var imageIn = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\sample-profile-image.jpeg");
byte[] bytes;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    bytes = ms.ToArray();   
}

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))
{
    System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms, true);
    image.Save(@"D:\Images\Photo.jpg");
}
```

**Updated: Use hex string**

```
string stringFrom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
var bytes = Enumerable.Range(0, stringFromSQL.Length)
                     .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                     .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(stringFromSQL.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                     .ToArray();

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))
{
    System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms, true);
    image.Save(@"D:\Images\Photo.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Here is one of the smalest valid image string: *0x47494638396101000100800000ffffffffffff21f904010a0001002c00000000010001000002024c01003b*

Comment: @sac1: please see my updated answer, your string is not valid though

Comment: @kinect89: I have replaced your string, and your code is working.
btw the problem is same, valid image byte array is requested.

Comment: @sac1: that's why you need to check your string and make sure it's correct at the first place